# Как задать запуск кода через pypy в VS Code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pypy

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как запускать код, написанный на `Python` через интерпретатор `Pypy` в `VS Code`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### При использовании расширения [ms-python.python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python):

1. Внизу слева в панели статуса там где указано имя текущего интерпретатора - нажать на его название, в появившемся меню выбрать `Enter interpreter path...` ("Ввести путь к интерпретатору"), через диалог открытия указать путь до `pypy3.exe` (или `pypy3`, если не Windows).

   [image: Screenshot]
2. После этого при запуске файла с расширением py с помощью зеленой стрелки (справа вверху на скриншоте), он будет запускаться выбранным интерпретатором:

   [image: Screenshot 2]

Так же, если путь pypy3 прописан в переменной окружения PATH, то можно прописать
`#! pypy3` в первой строке файла, тогда будет предложено установить pypy3 интерпретатором (`Set as interpreter`):

[image: Set as interpreter]

Нужно нажать на эту надпись, после этого выбранный интерпретатор внизу слева поменяется на pypy3 (будет написано что-то вроде `Python 3.6.12 32-bit`, но если навести на надпись, то в подсказке покажет путь к pypy).

---

#### При использовании расширения Code Runner ([formulahendry.code-runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner))

**Очень не рекомендую** данное расширение, т.к. оно игнорирует выбранный в панели статуса интерпретатор, в том числе интерпретатор из виртуального окружения.

- Прописать путь к pypy в PATH и указать `#! pypy3` в первой строке файла. При этом `Set as interpreter` не обязательно нажимать, т.к. это меняет выбранный интерпретатор в панели статуса, а расширение выбранный интерпретатор просто игнорирует, см. выше.
- Или через настройки расширения, пункт `Code-runner: Executor Map`, нажать `Edit in settings.json`, поменять там `"python": "python -u"` на `"python": "pypy3 -u"` - это поменяет интерпретатор по умолчанию для vscode глобально.