# Visual Studio Code не видит виртуального окружения

Tags: visual-studio-code, virtualenv

На машине установлены две версии python. 3.8 и 3.9. В Path прописана 3.9, потому по умолчанию всё открывается как последняя версия. Создавал виртуальную среду для проекта как через командную строку, так и через сам VSCode, активировал. Редактор не подгружает её. То есть в строке состояния вместо ..\venv\Scripts\python.exe, показывает С:\python39\python.exe.
Пробовал вручную указать на файл питона внутри проекта, но вместо этого он подгружает виртуальную среду из питона 3.8, хотя версия питона в проекте 3.9. Открывал, закрывал VScode, открывал через папку проекта - бесполезно.
Может у меня с настройками редактора что-то не то? Подскажите куда нужно смотреть.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пробовали щелкнуть по имени интерпретатора в строке состояния и указать путь к интерпретатору вручную? См. вот этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1215173/1365

Comment: Да, конечно. Первым делом

Comment: Виртуальное окружение создали из Python 3.9?

Comment: Да. Все файлы питона в проекте внутри папки "venv" версии 3.9

Comment: Если через cmd выполнить команду py, какая версия python откроется?

Comment: Python 3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21)

Comment: Так, а в файле pyenv.cfg внутри папки виртуального окружения какая версия Python прописана?

Comment: version_info = 3.9.6.final.0
virtualenv = 20.7.1
А так же все строчки указаны как версия 3.9

Comment: И при активированном окружении команда python запускает версию Python 3.8? Или vscode через зеленую стрелку запускает Python 3.8?

Comment: Да, но только в том случае, если вручную укажу на питон внутри проекта. А так вообще не воспринимает виртуалку. В терминале можно лазить по вирт. окружению спокойно, а в строке состояния не кажет.

Comment: Приложите скриншот, я не понимаю где у вас "не кажет". "если вручную укажу на питон внутри проекта" - как именно укажете?

Comment: Так, и в чем проблема, вам же 3.9 и нужно?

Comment: Мне нужно не просто 3.9, а с подключённой виртуальной средой)) А тут показывает глобально

Comment: Так, а если нажать на версию, выбрать "Enter interpreter path" и указать на python.exe внутри виртуального окружения?

Comment: Да, я так и делал

Comment: И в чем проблема?

Comment: Я потестировал, похоже, что если открывать папку проекта в vscode, а не одиночный файл, то достаточно один раз указать интерпретатор из виртуального окружения, и при каждом открытии этой папки в vscode автоматом будет выбираться последний выбранный для этой папки интерпретатор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Он не должен ничего подгружать, после того как активировали так

```
conda activate ./myenv
```

запуск Питона в shell (у меня анаконда)

```
python app.py
```

python.exe находит в myenv. Обязательно только изнутри `virtualenv shell` запускать(иначе может бинарники например `numpy` не подгрузить)(автоматизировать можно только запуск у меня анаконда консоли). Проверять версию Питона:

```
python --version
```

Куда настроены либы импрортов:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Хотя если это не anaconda, попробуйте переопределить путь так(1 строка),
Настраиваем ./.vscode/settings.json так:

```
{
"python.pythonPath": "myenv\\python.exe"
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows" : "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
"/K","activate.bat"
]
}
```

Потом правой кнопкой мыши на запускаемом скрипте и Run Python File in Terminal. Так запускал anaconda (venv) проекты, пока numpy pyd не перестали грузится, теперь все через shell.Оказывается можно автоматизировать, после того как shell активировали(или через cmd или через settings.json)->Потом правой кнопкой мыши на запускаемом скрипте и Run Python File in Terminal.Все работает.
PS.Бывает что даже после этого не видит(у меня было что виртуальное окружение было в другой папке), перезагрузка, просит ввести тот же самый интерпретатор (что у же есть в settings.json), вводим то же самый, видимо считывает, работает.

Comment: Не пользуюсь anaconda, при установленном расширении ms-python.python после выбора интерпретатора из виртуального окружения в левом нижнем углу при запуске зеленой стрелкой окружение автоматом активируется, и модуль запускается, ничего дополнительно настраивать не нужно.

Comment: Ну я анакондой, там в шеле должно происходить, а вопросу нужно переопределить python.pythonPath как я написал, так вернее сработает.